# Docker permission error when overlaying file system

Tags: linux, permissions, docker

I have 2 disk drives, one HDD and 1 SSD.

Im tyring to split the smaller, more commonly used files to be on the SSD and the larger less frequently used files to be on the HDD.
This has been working, I am now adding 1 more directory to be on the SSD

I have the following in docker-compose.yml

```
    volumes:
        - ./html:/var/www/html
        - ./data:/var/www/html/data
        - ./preview:/var/www/html/data/appdata/preview/
```

The bottom line (preview) is the one I am adding.

When adding the last line I get the following

```
ERROR: for container  Cannot start service container: OCI runtime create failed: container_linux.go:349: starting container process caused "process_linux.go:449: container init caused \"rootfs_linux.go:58: mounting \\\"/path/to/preview\\\" to rootfs \\\"/var/lib/docker/overlay2/6cf2fbd3f765322b65074279115acc2d0243a2bd8356bf9211794c734b7f22ce/merged\\\" at \\\"/var/www/html/data/appdata/preview\\\" caused \\\"lstat /var/lib/docker/overlay2/6cf2fbd3f765322b65074279115acc2d0243a2bd8356bf9211794c734b7f22ce/merged/var/www/html/data/appdata: permission denied\\\"\"": unknown
ERROR: Encountered errors while bringing up the project.
```

Im not 100% sure where this permission error is. I have checked apparmor, checked permissions of the 3 file mounts and all look correct.

The directory mounts correctly when mounting in the containers /tmp so I think its something to do with the nesting, is there a way to get more information about this ?

Answer (score 0):

`namei -l` in the container helped.

Root didnt have x permissions on one of the paths leading up to that directory so couldnt mount in there, adding +x to that directory fixed the issue